# flutter export nested packages with pubspec and assets for each

Tags: flutter, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

I'm trying to create re-usable and sharable modules for my different application.

I have created a git with root directory contains common widgets, hence, this root has its own pubspec.yml file with it's assets directory and packaged. In that root I have created a new directory for full modules (e.g. auth module) which by itself has its own pubspec.yml contains assets

```
| root
   | assets
   | pubspec.yml  # points to root assets
   | auth module
       | assets
       | pubspec.yml  # points to auth module assets (relative path)
```

in my app pubspec.yml. I'm pointing to this package as following:

```yaml
shared_libraries:  # the root package name
    git:
      url: https://github.com/.../shared_libraries.git
      ref: modules
```

in terms of widgets everything is working fine. but in terms of assets, the auth module assets are not loaded at all, hence, the internal pubspec yml of auth was not called ?

How can I make sure to call all nests pubspecs of my root package ?